# ¿Como cargar backups in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

He intentado cargar un backup de una base de datos en SQL-Server y siempre recibo un mensaje como este:

> Backup mediaset is not complete. Files: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\backup_22032021.bak`. Family count:3. Missing family sequence number:1

¿Me podrían decir como cargar ese backup?

Comment: El error te está diciendo que ese `.bak` es sólo **una parte** del backup de la BD. Cuando ese backup fue generado, se creó en **tres partes distintas** y el mensaje te está diciendo que estás intentando cargar la **primera parte**. Tienes las otras dos?

Comment: Bueno pude asumir que las partes eran aquellas que estaban indexadas en el espacio de la parte de abajo cuando se iba a generar el backup, incluso lo puse con los mismos nombres los directorios y todo, pero nada, le pongo las 3 direcciones y entonces me sigue diciendo lo mismo en el error